# How to get the value in object based on the largest key (Date is an Key)

Tags: javascript, date, object, keyvaluepair

I having the Object with Date as Key and Value as Locations. I want Get the locations based on the largest Date. Here the locations are same. The Date Key is in "MM/DD/YYYY" Format.

```
var obj ={};
    obj['9/10/2016'] = "India-Chennai";
    obj['9/15/2016'] = "Australia-Melborne";
    obj['9/20/2016'] = "India-Delhi";
    obj['9/25/2016'] = "India-Chennai";
```

Form the above object the largest Date(Key) is "9/25/2016" and the value would be "India-Chennai" How to get the value based on the largest key?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Keys are strings...

Comment: `obj[9/10/2016]` ==> `bj['9/10/2016']`

Comment: you can't have duplicate properties

Comment: *"For example i want to get the Location of Australia"* - But that would mean testing both the *keys* to get the largest date, *and* the *values* to filter out any that don't mention Australia. And although the code you've shown is valid JS that will run, the result is not at all what you want (for the reasons mentioned in the other comments).

Comment: I have edited the question , to scenario, i need to get the location based largest key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, `Math.max()`, `Date.prototype.getTime()`, `Array.prototype.indexOf()`

```js
var obj = {};
obj['9/10/2016'] = "India-Chennai";
obj['9/15/2016'] = "Australia-Melborne";
obj['9/20/2016'] = "India-Delhi";
obj['9/25/2016'] = "India-Chennai";

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var map = keys.map(function(date) {return new Date(date).getTime()});
var key = Math.max.apply(Math, map);
var value = obj[keys[map.indexOf(key)]];

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might do something like this;

```js
var obj = {},
 latest = [];
  obj['9/20/2016'] = "India-Delhi";
  obj['9/10/2016'] = "Japan-Osaka";
  obj['9/25/2016'] = "India-Chennai";
  obj['9/15/2016'] = "Australia-Melborne";
  
 latest = obj[Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime())[0]];
 console.log(latest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get a list of keys as an array, then `.sort()` that array:

```js
var obj ={};
obj['9/10/2016'] = "India-Chennai";
obj['9/9/2016'] = "Australia-Melborne";
obj['9/25/2016'] = "India-Chennai";
obj['9/20/2016'] = "India-Delhi";
    
var parseDate = d => (d = d.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/)) && new Date(d[3],d[1]-1,d[2]);
var latestKey = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => parseDate(a) - parseDate(b)).pop();
var result = obj[latestKey];

console.log(latestKey, result);
```

I've used a regex to parse the dates, so that the code can easily be adapted to other date formats, e.g., if you needed d/m/yyyy instead of m/d/yyyy.

Comment: Only answer to correctly parse the strings. Though I'd use `d.split(/\D/)` so any non–digit separator can be used. ;-)